# Overridden private method is causing exception in accessing subclass public method in Java

Tags: java

The below program is giving compilation error in line "obj.method()" inside the main method. The error is "The method method() from the type Superclass is not visible". From my understanding it should be able to access public method of subclass. can anyone explain the concept behind it?

```
class Superclass{

private void method(){
    System.out.println("Inside superclass method");
}

}

public class MyClass extends Superclass{

     public void method(){
        System.out.println("Inside subclass method");
    }

    public static void main(String s[]){

        Superclass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.method();

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot override private methods, if absolutely want to override, declare it as protected/public.

Answer (score 3):

> From my understanding it should be able to access public method of subclass.

Yes, but only when the *compile-time type* of the expression you're calling it on is that subclass.

So if you change your code to:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

then it should be fine. Currently, the compile-time type of `obj` is just `Superclass`, which *doesn't* have a public `method` method.

Also note that `MyClass.method` does *not* override `Superclass.method`. A call to `method()` within `Superclass` would only call `Superclass.method()` even if the actual type of the object was `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks all for you answers. I got the concept.

Answer (score 1):

`method` is declared `private` in `Superclass`. `private` means that it will only be accessible within that class. If you want subclasses to be able to access it (or override it), you have to declare it `protected` instead.

Comment: I will remark to your answer that If you want to override a method that is already defined in a superclass, you must need to add `@Override` annotation. Probably your IDE will suggest it to you.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOux You don't need to, in general. But it's adviced, since it would give a compile time warning that you're not in fact overriding any methods in this case.

Comment: Yep, I said 'you must need', but it's optional :)

Answer (score 0):

`obj` has reference of `SuperClass`. So it can only see `SuperClass` methods which are `protected`,`default` or `public`.
Private methods are visible only inside the class.

```
No Overriding happens here.
```

Comment: obj is an instance of MyClass